# Unable to filter MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

What's the proper way to filter a collection in MongoDB? I need to filter the array by the ID number.

```js
var collection = db.collection('blog');

try {

  collection.find().toArray(function(err, result) {

    if (err) { 
      console.log('Error:', err);
    } else {

      res.render('blogEntry', {
        title: 'Blog Entry',
        session: req.session,
        blog: result
      });

      db.close();
    }

  });

} catch (Exception) {
  console.log('there was a problem when accessing collection');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.find({ _id: "apple" }).toArray...
```

The method takes two parameters:

```
collection.find(query, projection)
```

If you leave them empty, you fetch everything.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: you have to replace apple with your id?

Comment: Well yeah, but it still wasn't filtering anything back. I saw your same method on some other posts. For some reason that object Id needs to be there otherwise it was coming back as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed to do.

```js
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

collection.find({
  _id: ObjectID(blogId)
}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  callback(result);
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: The thing is it's a required value.